# Initiating UITalbleViewController in the code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have `UITableViewController` in my `storyboard` in which there are three cell with on label in the middle on each.
For instance if a user clicks on the first cell label in show a another `tableview` with list of Items by selecting an item it get back to the previous `tableView` and the item name should be printed in the place of the label.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface carSelectCellTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *carMake;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *carModel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *carRego;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *carYear;

//the below label are the labels in the cells.
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *carSelected;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *location;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *service;
@end

#import "BookService.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "carSelectCellTableViewCell.h"
@interface BookService ()
@end

@implementation BookService

@synthesize tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"cell tabbed");
    PFObject *temp = [customerCars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@", temp.objectId);
    NSString *car = temp.objectId;
        UIStoryboard *dashboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *change = [dashboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"bookAservice"];
    [self presentViewController:change animated:YES completion:nil];
    static NSString *Identifier = @"carSelectedCell";
   //here is where i'm calling the cell to change the label value when the selection is made. before dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier there should be appropriate tableView Table.
    carSelectCellTableViewCell *cell2 = [dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier];
   cell2.carSelected.text = @"selcted";

}
```

How can i  programmatically initiate the tableView. So that i can change the cell label value to the selected item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now If u suppose the First table View is names as ParentViewController and the second table view as childView u can do the Foll:

To do this make ParentController a delegate of ChildController. This allows ChildController to send a message back to ParentController enabling us to send data back.

For ParentController to be delegate of ChildController it must conform to ChildController's protocol which we have to specify. This tells ParentController which methods it must implement.

In ChildController.h, below the #import, but above @interface you specify the protocol.

```
@class ChildController;

@protocol ViewControllerBDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)addItemViewController:(ChildController *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSString *)item;
@end
```

next still in the ChildController.h you need to setup a delegate property in ChildController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ChildControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

In ChildController we call a message on the delegate when we pop the view controller.

For this case the following will be called in `didSelectRowAtIndex` method

```
NSString *itemToPassBack = @"Pass this value back to ParentController";
[self.delegate addItemViewController:self didFinishEnteringItem:itemToPassBack];
```

That's it for ChildController. Now in ParentController.h, tell ParentViewController to import Child and conform to its protocol.

## import "ChildController.h"

@interface ParentController : UIViewController 
In ParentController.m implement the following method from our protocol

```
- (void)addItemViewController:(ChildController *)controller didFinishEnteringItem:(NSString *)item
{
    NSLog(@"This was returned from ChildController %@",item);
}
```

The last thing we need to do is tell ChildController that ParentController is its delegate before we push ChildController on to nav stack.

```
ChildController *ChildController = [[ChildController alloc] initWithNib:@"ChildController" bundle:nil];
ChildController.delegate = self
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:ChildController animated:YES];
```